# Strip hash from url

Tags: javascript, jquery, hash

How do get the hash url to output something cleaner? Its doing this:

*domain.com/#/page/1*

When I want it to do this:

*domain.com/page/1*

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

        var newHash = '';

        $('#wrapper a').live('click', function(e){
            if (this.hostname && this.hostname == location.hostname) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var link = $(this).attr('href');
                window.location.hash = link;
            }
        });

        $(window).bind('hashchange', function() {
            newHash = window.location.hash.substr(1);
            $('#content').fadeOut(100).load(newHash + ' #contentInner', function(){
                $('#content').fadeIn(100); 
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: Those are two completely different URLs. They point to different resources. The first points to the domain.com default index, the second to /page/1 of domain.com. Everything before the hash describes the resource name and optional parameters, and everything after is an anchor with the resource that is usually handled by the client.

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, you need the [HTML5 history API](http://diveintohtml5.org/history.html) to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (location.href.indexOf("#") > -1) {
    location.assign(location.href.replace(/\/?#\//, "/"));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try :

```
var url = "domain.com/#/page/1";
var noHash = url.split("/#").join("");
```

Answer (score 1):

That's what a hash is supposed to look like - the `#` portion is the hash. If you don't want a hash in your url, then do:

```
window.location = link;
```

instead.